# Render shows up as solid colour but shading looks fine

Tags: rendering

I've searched around but I couldn't find anything. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: What you show is a Material Preview, which uses an internal HDRI, but for the final render you need to have an HDRI if you want to have a proper reflection on this kind of very reflective texture

Comment: @moonboots, so sorry, I literally started blender a few days ago so I don't know what u mean. Can u please explain?

Comment: @Chris how do I add the blend file.

Comment: what do you see if you click on the Rendered Preview (fourth button on the top right of your 3D view, you have currently selected the third which is Material Preview, which is not what you'll get for render)

Comment: @moonboots thanks, how do I add the HDRI?

Comment: just use dropbox/googledrive or any other cloud service and paste the link to the question

Comment: @Chris I'll never understand why you ask for a blend file on questions like this. You don't need his boat model to explain the difference between a _Material Preview_ and the _Render Preview_.

Answer (score 1):

In the 3D view you have chosen the *Material Preview*, it will use a default HDRI image (360° image) as environment but if you select the *Rendered Preview* (fourth button) you'll see that for the moment your scene has no HDRI image, so your water has nothing to reflect for the final render:

[image]

Look for an HDRI (for example on [polyhaven.org](https://polyhaven.org)) Open the *Shader Editor*, switch it to *World*, plug an *(Input) Texture Coordinate* node into a *(Texture) Environment Texture* that you plug into the *Background*. Click on the *Open* button of the *Environment Texture* and select the HDRI:

[image]